# iFrame on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have "auto-created" links by loop from the database, and when I click on a link it should show an iframe, it works with the first link only. And doesn't work with the others...

First the code which prints the data

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wr))
{
printf(nl2br("<a class='questions' id='oldQ'><b>%s</b></a>\n\n"), $row['question'], $row['question']);
}
```

Then the code which create the iframe

```
document.getElementById('oldQ').onclick = function() {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = "qa.php";
iframe.class = "iframe";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use same `id` for multiple html elements. Either assign an unique `id` to each iframe, or don't assign them `id`s at all - use classes instead:

```
printf(nl2br("<a class='questions oldQ'>...
```

and then

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('oldQ');
for (i in elements) {
    elements[i].onclick = ...
}
```

Comment: I've deleted the "oldQ" and used `document.getElementsByClassName` with `questions` but now it doesn't work at all

Comment: Edited the answer - since we now query for multiple elements, we need a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the same html `id` to every item in the while loop, and then using that id in the javascript lookup.